# Infragistics Ultra Grid Make cell input type uppercase only

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics

I have an infragistics UltraGrid and i want to make it as , it should take uppercase alphabets only. No matter capslock is on or off.

Comment: Have you tried Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.Case.Upper ?

Comment: yes but this didn't worked for me. Help

Answer (score 5):

Use `e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns[OrderFields.CAPTION_SName].CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;`